# Profiler to analyze Sitefinty page load step by step

Tags: .net, performance, profiler, sitefinity, sitefinity-6.x

I should speed up a Sitefinity site (6.2) which is really-really slow.

I modified already the configuration (ie. *debug=false*) but it's still 1-2 minute to load a page(!). One way is to check IIS/MSSQL performace problems, but I would like to investigate Sitefinity too.

Is there any Sitefinty-ready (or just friendly) profiler to show

- method-call graph
- time per method
- maybe raw sql queries and running times

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend JustTrace, it's a Telerik product. You can get a 30 day trial.

http://www.telerik.com/products/memory-performance-profiler.aspx

I've used it on multiple occasions to track down code causing "bottlenecks"

Answer (score 1):

Later versions of Sitefinity have a Diagnostics module built-in that could help identify long running DB queries, etc.

http://docs.sitefinity.com/overview-performance-diagnostics-module

Comment: Yes, but we are using 6.2